# How to enable code map feature in JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

How to enable code map feature in PhpStorm like it is in Sublime etc?

[image]

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235583/how-to-get-a-code-map-for-intellij-idea

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Code Outline and Code Outline 2 are old plugins that are not compatible with latest IDE versions. CodeGlance plugin only (out of all known to me options).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such feature available in IDEA-based IDEs out of the box.

The corresponding ticket is located in the Backlog project .. so it's quite unlikely to became a native feature any time soon.

In any case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5794 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

In the meantime -- install **CodeGlance plugin** -- it does just that.

Comment: CodeGlance plugin and CodeGlance2 plugin destroy code formatting. If you have problems with formatting your PHP code - propobly the plugin is the problem

Comment: @Kafus Do you have any details on this "destroy code formatting" issue? Any tickets with the plugin author or alike (that I can see). I'm not using this plugin myself (I'm fine withought such functionality) but interested in reading on the issue.